# In Vue.js, why am I getting an error when trying to migrate to a single file component?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have followed the tutorial here:

http://frankclark.xyz/veevalidate-strong-password-and-confirmation-validation

to create a custom password validator.

I'm now trying to move that code into a single file component.

I have created a file called Password.vue and have put the HTML within `<template></template>` tags without issue.

But when I add the JavaScript:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

VeeValidate.Validator.extend('verify_password', {
    getMessage: field => `The password must contain at least: 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and one special character (E.g. , . _ & ? etc)`,
    validate: value => {
        var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
        return strongRegex.test(value);
    }
});
```

inside `<script></script>` tags, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In general, I would't suggest you  to use `veevalidate` because it's pretty big in size. It's better to use `vuelidate`. Feel the difference: 84kb vs 24kb

Comment: Could you provide whole code of you `Password.vue` file?

Comment: Probably need to to add `export default {}` to the end of the file